# How to extract the date time from a string using bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have the below strings and from those i need to extract the data and time. I were trying to get these using awk command i am unable to find our the solution. The below lined are the put put of

```
grep -ir 'can not save data' Aplication-aplicationName-server0046704* | awk -F' GMT' '{print$1}' | grep -v 'can not save data'
```

```
Aplication-aplicationName-server0046704.log.1:2020 May 27 10:23:16:147
Aplication-aplicationName-server0046704.log.bkp:2020 May 27 10:23:16:147
```

desired output :

```
2020 May 27 10:23:16:147
```

Comment: Actually i did a small modification in the grep. i used grep -h to avoid the file name in the output

Comment: What is output of `grep -ir 'can not save data' Aplication-aplicationName-server0046704*`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^[^:]+://' | uniq
```

Explanation:

- The `sed` command will remove everything before the first `:`
  and the first `:`
- The `uniq` command will remove every duplicate

Using `cut`:

```
cut -d ':' -f2- | uniq
```

Explanation:

- `cut` will accept as delimeter a `:` (`-d ':'`) and will print the fields
  from the second to the end (`-f2-`)
- The `uniq` command will remove every duplicate